# React.js: I can’t write a callback for the exchange between two child components through the parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have three components: App (parent component) and two child components (game, play). There is a function in the child component of game  that assigns a green color to a random div.  I need to transfer this function through the parent component and connect to the  Play  button of the second child component (Play).

```js
App (parent component)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Game from './components/Game/game';
import Play from './components/Play/play';

export default class App extends Component {

        state = {
            sizeEasyMode: undefined,
            sizeNormalMode: undefined,
            sizeHardMode: undefined,

            delayTimeEasyMode: undefined,
            delayTimeNormalMode: undefined,
            delayTimeHardMode: undefined,
            number: 20,
        }

    async componentDidMount () {
        const response = await
            fetch(URL) // data comes to form the size div (height and width)
        const gameSettings = await response.json();

        this.setState({
           // Div size is formed (height and width) from URL
        })
}
    cellColor=()=>{                  // my attempt to write a callback
        this.setState({number:24})
        }
  
    render (){

        return (
            <div>
            <div className="d-flex">
                <form>
                    <button>Play</button>
                </form>
            </div>
                < Game
                    cellColor={this.cellColor}
                    x={this.state.x}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Game (child component)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Game extends Component {



    render() {
        const duel = ['duel1', 'duel2', 'duel3', 'duel4', 'duel5', 'duel6', 'duel7',
            'duel8', 'duel9', 'duel10', 'duel11', 'duel12', 'duel13', 'duel14',
            'duel15', 'duel16', 'duel17', 'duel18', 'duel19', 'duel20', 'duel21',
            'duel22', 'duel23', 'duel24', 'duel25'];


  // this function needs to be connected to a child component of Play
        let numRandom = () => {
           let randomNumber = duel[Math.round(Math.random() * this.props.cellColor + 1)];
           let rancellGreen = document.getElementById(randomNumber).style.backgroundColor='green'
           }

        return (
            <div onClick={()=>{
                this.props.cellColor();
             }}>

                <div id='duel1'></div>
                <div id='duel2'></div>
                <div id='duel3'></div>
                <div id='duel4'></div>
                <div id='duel5'></div>
                <div id='duel6'></div>
                <div id='duel7'></div>
                <div id='duel8'></div>
                <div id='duel9'></div>
                <div id='duel10'></div>
                <div id='duel11'></div>
                <div id='duel12'></div>
                <div id='duel13'></div>
                <div id='duel14'></div>
                <div id='duel15'></div>
                <div id='duel16'></div>
                <div id='duel17'></div>
                <div id='duel18'></div>
                <div id='duel19'></div>
                <div id='duel20'></div>
                <div id='duel21'></div>
                <div id='duel22'></div>
                <div id='duel23'></div>
                <div id='duel24'></div>
                <div id='duel25'></div>
         </div>
        );
    }
}


Play (child component)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Play extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.cellColor}>Play</button>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your problem is on `<div onClick={()=>{this.props.cellColor}}` 
Cell color is a function and you are not executing it. Try this `<div onClick={this.props.cellColor}` or this `<div onClick={()=>this.props.cellColor()}`

Comment: Both options do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to trigger a function that is defined in `Game` in the sibling component `Play`? I'm not sure if that's possible... It is also not a good design choice. If you find yourself wanting child components talk to each other, you should instead put the common information inside a parent component.

Something like this minimal snippet maybe...

```js
function App(){
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState()
  function playing(){
    setNum(Math.floor(5 * Math.random()))
  }
  return <div><Play playing={playing}/><Game num={num}/></div>
}
function Game(props){
  const divArr = [0,1,2,3,4]
  return(<div>
    {divArr.map((arr, i) => <div 
       className={i===props.num?'square green':'square'}></div>)}
  </div>)
}
function Play(props){
  return <button onClick={props.playing}>Play</button>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.square{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.green{
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

It's functional components here, but the idea is the same. The state is `num` and is passed to `Game` and the function that changes it is passed to `Play`.

Not that in the code you posted there are many parts that are not important to your question. Always post minimal code that clarifies your problem.

Although you defined the `Play` component you never actually use it. The same is true for the function `numRandom`. You define it inside of `Game`'s render method, but you never call it.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution, but for my experience this option is difficult, although I understand well what you wanted to say. I wanted to raise the numRandom function to the parent component via the cellColor callbask using the number argument and connect numRandom to the button in the Play component via props. Thanks for the help. I understood my main mistake. Through callback, I can not raise this function to the parent component, I will redo the entire architecture of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Lift the state up higher, then pass it down to the children as props.
If you need the child to be in charge of "when" the action occurs then you pass a function down as a prop (fetchGameData), then let the parent component manage state and pass it down as props.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked out. The topic is closed. I moved the root div from the "Game" component to the "App". Accordingly, the function "numRandom" has been moved to the "App". I want to express my deep gratitude to the real React.js professors who suggested the ways to solve the problem.